# Reading Third Word of File Input (C++)

Tags: c++, file-io

So I am doing a practice exam for one of my classes, but I'm stuck as to how to solve the problem. We are given the following C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main​() {
ifstream infile("princes.txt");
string s;

while(________________)
{
    cout << s << endl;
}
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And where the ________ is, we are supposed to fill in code to properly generate the desired output. We are not allowed to modify the code besides the underscored area. The file we are reading in from called "princes.txt" and the desired output are:

```
"Princes.txt"
Prince of Persia
Prince of Wales
Prince of Bel-Air
Prince of Egypt

Desired Output:
Persia
Wales
Bel-Air
Egypt
```

I'm stuck on how to only read the third word of each line using only the underscored area. I know how to read the whole line with `getLine` or three separate Strings where we could just output the third String each time, but since we're not allowed to modify anything else, I'm lost.

Comment: Also, we are not allowed to use anything from any libraries besides what is already included

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
while(infile>>s && infile>>s  && infile>>s)
```

which could clobber the first 2 s values?

Comment: You don't need the '&&'. Just use infile >> s >> s >> s

Answer (score 0):

while (!(infile.eof()) || ++x%3)
That might work